# Error with Hibernate JPA request

Tags: hibernate, jpa

how can I do this :

SELECT c.categoriesThemes FROM Categorie c WHERE c.url = :url AND c.categoriesThemes.id != 5

This is problematic : c.categoriesThemes.id != 5

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.categoriesThemes FROM Categorie c WHERE c.url = :url AND c.categoriesThemes.id <> 5
```

Comment: down vote
accept
 

Thanks a lot but i have this error :

org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [categorie0_.id.categoriesThemes] with element property reference [id] [SELECT c.categoriesThemes FROM com.warez.iodos.model.Categorie c WHERE c.url = :url AND c.categoriesThemes.id <> 5]

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the item type you want is `CategoryTheme` and the category's property name is `category`, you'd need a query kind of like this

```
SELECT ct FROM CategoryTheme ct WHERE ct.category.url = :url AND ct.id <> 5
```

Basically, you are trying to select from the wrong table.

Comment: Is not bidirectionnel... I d'ont have categorie in categoriesThemes

Comment: Then you'll have to use native queries, because JPQL is limited by your relations.

Answer (score 0):

So, i have create a bidirectionnel and now, this request is ok

```
SELECT ct FROM CategorieTheme ct JOIN ct.categorie c WHERE c.url = :url AND ct.id <> 5
```

But not this :

```
SELECT c.categoriesThemes FROM Categorie c JOIN c.categoriesThemes ct WHERE c.url = :url AND ct.id <> 5
```

Why ?